# Calling a Stripe checkout form from a custom button

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, stripe-payments

I have the following [price table.](http://www.lucidwebgrouptest.com/test-table-page/) Please note that this is not the actual table I want to modify but all of the HTML and CSS is identical.

I would like to call the [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) checkout form using the [Simple Strike Checkout plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stripe/) when the customer clicks the submit button.

According to the documentation [here](http://wpstripe.net/docs/getting-started/simple-stripe-checkout-faq), I need use custom JQuery and follow the instructions for the question "How do I call the checkout form from a custom button or link?"

Specifically, I need to follow this section

> Each Stripe form is assigned it’s own unique “id” attribute, such as "sc_checkout_form_1", >"sc_checkout_form_2", etc. You’ll simply need to trigger the submit event of your targeted form.
>
> For example, to trigger the first Stripe form on a page with a button containing the id >“my_custom_button”, use this script:
>
> `jQuery('#my_custom_button').click(function(e) {
>    e.preventDefault();
>    jQuery('#sc_checkout_form_1').submit();
>   });`

The problem I having is that my buttons do not have a unique ID attribute that allow me to identify them. After contacting Phil Derksen at Stripe support, he suggested, "You'll need to use the element's class or somehow pinpoint how to detect a click even on each specific button element."

Would anybody be able to expand on this and provide a more specific solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to traverse the DOM in jQuery - http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating

Or perhaps quicker / easier way you could just place the html (copying from the source code) that the shortcode in your wordpress theme created, then editing that in the text view in wordpress, so you could assign a ID element to your button!

I hope that gives some help, let me know how you got on.

Answer (score 0):

Try following link: [Checkout - v2](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/v2)

Refer the custom button section. You just need to identify your custom button through jQuery. If not ID then by class or traversing through each controls on the page and identify the button based on some property. And then attach the event.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

- data-amount is represented in cents
- value is the display text
- data-billing-address adds billing address fields
- data-shipping-address adds shipping address fields

**HTML CODE**

```
<input 
    type="button" 
    class="stripeBtn"
    value="Proceed to Checkout"
    data-key="***"
    data-description="***"
    data-amount= ***
    data-currency="usd"
    data-name="***"
    data-billing-address="true"
    data-shipping-address="true"
    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"/>
```

**Event Handler**

- make sure to load stripejs and JQuery before handler
- POST uses JQuery method
- expects a callback from server ex NODE **res.send('/charged')**

**JS CODE**

```
$('.stripeBtn').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var $button = $(this);
var opts = $.extend({}, $button.data(), {
    token: function(result, args) {
      //result contains token and card info
      //args contains for shipping and billing info

      //disable stripe button
      $('.stripeBtn').prop('disabled', true);

      //POST to route
      $.post( "/charge",{ 
        token: result.id,
        card: result.card, 
        email: result.email, 
        args: args}).success(function(data) {
        //data is the callback
        window.location = data;
      });;
    }
});
StripeCheckout.open(opts);
});
```